# I am looking for a way to eliminate duplicate values in a column while using row_number over , partition by in MySQL

Tags: mysql, row-number, partition-by

The column Product in the below image has duplicate values. However, I want all the columns with duplicate values except for the Product column

[image]

The query I wrote is this:

```
SELECT
            DISTINCT product_name, id, date, customer_id, row_number () over
           (partition by customer_idorder by date DESC) as rn
        FROM
           mvmt_dtl e 
        WHERE
            mvt_date_id_part_key >= '2020-01-01' and
            customer_id IN
            (SELECT a.line_number from simp_output_dci a)
            order by customer_id
```

What I need:
Product table should include Product P1, Product P2 only. Within each partition of customer_id I want to have unique values under the Product column.

Could somebody help to get this sorted?

Thank you

Comment: Edit your question and show what results you want.

Comment: @DhvaniShah Your explanation of the required output hasn't helped. Include some sample output in the format you want it.